# Is label best fit for image with Rmagick possible?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

> The biggest trick to using labels to generate images of a specific "-size" is NOT to specify a "-pointsize" for the label. When this happens IM will have the freedom to try and select a font size that best fits the image size requested. That is the drawn text will be adjusted to fit the given size!  [1](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label_bestfit)

This extract from the ImageMagick documentation show that it's pretty easy to force text to fit inside a image size.

I've try to find a way to fit text inside a fix width Rmagick image without success.

```
    text = Draw.new
    text.annotate layer, layer_data['width'], layer_data['height'], layer_data['x'], layer_data['y'], layer_content do

      self.font_family = 'arial'
      self.fill = '#000000'

    end
```

I've logically tried to use annotate without a pointsize, but Rgmagick just swap the default pointsize of 12.

Is there a way with Rmagick to let the library compute the best pointsize so text fit in a fixed width image, like in ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently found a way to achieve this result. I was never able to find the point-size to use to fit the text within a bounding box, and was at first using `get_type_metrics` to calculate an X and Y scale for me to use.

```
metrics = text.get_type_metrics(image_canvas, image_text)

x_scale = container_width > metrics.width ? (container_width / metrics.width) : (metrics.width / container_width)
y_scale = container_height > metrics.height ? (container_height / metrics.height) : (metrics.height / container_height)
scale = container_height > metrics.height ? [x_scale, y_scale].min : [x_scale, y_scale].max
```

However, that felt a little flaky, and have recently been using this little snippet instead.

```
image_canvas = Magick::Image.new(canvas_width, canvas_height)

text_container = Magick::Image.read("label:#{image_text}") {
    self.stroke = 'transparent'
    self.fill = '#0000A9'
    self.size = "#{text_container_width}x#{text_container_height}"
}.first

image_canvas.composite!(text_container, text_x_offset, text_y_offset, Magick::SrcOverCompositeOp)
```

Basically all this does is create a main image (if you wanted to have multiple elements on the image, and overlays a `Magick::Image` object on top of the main image acting as the auto-sized text element.

Or if you are after multi-line text, you can change `label` to `caption` like so: `Magick::Image.read("caption:#{image_text}")`